# Help with lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method:

```
static double NewtonMethodModified(Func<double, double> f, double x0, double h) { ... }
```

Now, I'd like to know how to call it the following way:

```
NewtonMethodModified(<lambda expression here>, 1.0, 1.0);
```

I'd guess this should be something like

```
NewtonMethodModified(x => 10x-5, 1.0, 1.0);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should already work - just add a `*` (it still uses C#-style operators, not implicit math operations such as "10x === 10 * x"):

```
NewtonMethodModified(x => 10*x-5, 1.0, 1.0);
```